# Why is the frustum of a cone used to slump test of concrete and not a cylindrical tube?

Tags: materials, civil-engineering, concrete

While performing the slump test for knowing the workability of a concrete mix one uses a tube having the shape of frustum of a cone in order to conduct the test. Why is not a cylindrical tube used instead?

Answer (score 3):

Because the cone with frustrum has a longer time constant and also more stability compared to a cylinder.

This gives results measured in seconds and tens of seconds instead of fractions - unless you are testing really failed mixes like 90% water.